# Generating RSA private key wrapped using AES

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I am new to encryption and been playing with openssl. There's a command in openssl to generate an RSA private key wrapped using AES:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128
```

And the sample result will be:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,7787EC23BAB71A7E339FA4BB5B197362

Sqmr8Zb8..bla..blaa
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In PyCrypto, we can build the similar private key using:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(1024).exportKey('PEM', 'secret')
```

Which will produce

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,760A8103AA096360

HxGmbla..blaa
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Notice the result is wrapped using triple DES. What is the proper way to create a private key wrapped using AES such as the one above using PyCrypto?

Comment: AES is symmetric.  Public/private means non-symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

AES encryption of RSA keys will be only supported in PyCrypto 2.7 (right now there is an alpha version available on the web site). However, AES encryption will be applied at the PKCS#8 level (binary) and not at the PEM level (the text envelope).

That is not what you ask but it is way better, because the key stretching routine used for PEM is not secure.

You will do for instance:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(2048)

print key.exportKey('PEM', 'secret', pkcs=8, protection='PBKDF2WithHMAC-SHA1AndAES256-CBC')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the last commit to PyCrypto was in October 2013. PyCrypto 2.7 was never released.

Comment: @malina There is also [PyCryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) available as replacement for PyCrypto.

Comment: Thanks @SquareRootOfTwentyThree, PyCryptodome did indeed support an AES-encrypted RSA private key. I wasn't aware of the alternate package, seems to be kept very up to date and well documented. Thanks again for the link!